# Density of $H^1$ functions with bounded gradient

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, semigroup-of-operators

I have been working on a PDE problem and I came across the need of working with functions with bounded gradient. However, since I am working with semigroups, I need density of the domain of the generator candidate. So my question is: for a fixed $C>0$, is the set $$X = \left\{f \in H^1(0,1); f(1) = 0 \ \mbox{and} \ |f_x(x)| \leqslant C \ \mbox{for all } x \in (0,1)\right\}$$ dense in $L^2(0,1)$ with the $L^2$--norm?

Any hint on how to prove or disprove this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: My first idea would be that f(1)=0 and $|f'|\leq C$ implies $|f(0)|\leq C$, so maybe there should be an f with $|f(0)| > C$ that has trouble being approximated with functions of bounded gradient.

Comment: Indeed, this set is bounded in $L^2$ by @lisyarus's argument. That means it's far away from being dense.

Answer (score 1):

lisyarus' point hits close to home. For almost every $x \in [0, 1]$ and any $f \in X$ we have:
$$
\lvert f(x) \rvert = \lvert f(x) - 0 \rvert = \lvert f(x) - f(1) \rvert = \left \lvert \int^1_x f_x(s)~\mathrm{d}s \right \rvert \leq \lvert x -1 \rvert C\leq C
$$
So let us assume that there is some sequence $(g_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq X$ to approximate $g(x) := C+1$ in $L^2$. We know that there is a subsequence $g_{m_n}$ of $g_n$ that converges pointwise a.e. to $g$.

In fact for almost every $x$:
$$
C\geq \lvert g_{m_n}(x) \rvert \rightarrow \lvert g(x) \rvert = C+1
$$
So $C \geq C+1$ which is nonsense.

This means that $X$ is not dense.